# Back to the dafault Schema after flyway migration

Tags: flyway

Is it possible that flyway leave dataSource connected to the schema used in migration which is different from the default dataSource schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flyway obtains connections from the supplied datasource. On these connections, if the schemas property is set, the default schema is set to the first schema in the list.

This setting is only valid at the connection level. If you don't reuse the connection, you shouldn't see any changes.

Comment: By default I meant connection specified in the JDBC connection URL. I reuse connections from connection pool. That means the connection can be pointed to a different schema after it used in migration process?

Comment: Correct. This has been addressed on master and will be fixed in 2.2.